# AngularJS dropdown multiselect doesn't unchecked when selection change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fnGPAMzs78g5GC0pS5zH?p=preview) that has an example of angularjs dropdown multiselect ,
my problem is when selection limit is 1 and has a selectd model when I click to any other item in the list is doesn't change the selection until uncheck the previous one, any one have an experience in angularjs can solve the problem which is prevent select item until unselect the previous item?

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

myApp.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Angularjs-multiselect-dropdown";
  $scope.example6model = [{id: 1}, {id: 3}]; 
  $scope.example6data = [{id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}]; 
  $scope.example6settings = {};

  $scope.example65model = [{id: 1}]; 
  $scope.example65data = [{id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}]; 
  $scope.example65settings = {selectionLimit: 1};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a single object as model and not an array when you have single selection functionality enabled.

Such as:

```
$scope.example65model = {id: 1};
```

You can see an example in the [documentation](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) in "Single Selection Limit" area.

Comment: thank you very much ,working 100%. you saved 2 weeks of my working